# Should I wait for the install to complete before playing?

Tags: xbox-one

This is strictly related to the Xbox One as I do not know how the process works for PS4.

During the installation process of a game, the notification comes up "***Ready to Start***".

I've noticed on some games that even though it said it was ready, I couldn't play the game. It would bring me to the start screen but when I tried to start, it would tell me to wait until installation is complete.

Is there any risk to start playing games while they are still installing? Possible data corruption of the install, or save game data?

Comment: Not sure this is easy to prove really, because it can corrupt itself during download and you could blame it on anything at that point.  However, I will say with how computers work, it cannot use any files/assets that are not complete (it can still try and fail).  So think of it this way, it should not corrupt anything by trying, but your game may not work correctly until it finishes (which may mean closing and starting the game back up later).  Save game data is separate, but I can't say for sure whether it would affect that or not.  Remember, this is based off of computers, not an XBox One.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been informed a game was ready to start only to find that it needed to download more a few times. It's a little frustrating.

I've never had any issues with corruption or anything like that as a result of playing the game once it finally let me. If the game allows you to play it before the download is 100% complete, that is by design, so it shouldn't be any more likely to corrupt your data then any other time it is operating by design.

That being said, not all development houses are created equal, and sometimes bugs will slip through. So, no one can tell you *definitively* that this will *never* happen. You should be fine, though.